# How to get print information or text stored in JTxtArea with specific page size through Printer

Tags: java

i want to get print with specific page size, this will be use in a shoe shop so that i also need to get print direct and fast way please help me

Things 
1: specific page
2: Direct and fast way to print

try {jTextArea1.print();
        } catch (PrinterException ex) {
            Logger.getLoggeenter code herer(PrintBill.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Checkout out the [`javax.print`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/print/package-summary.html) package and [Lesson: Printing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html). Here's quick n' dirty example of what you could do:

```
Doc document = new SimpleDoc(jTextArea1.getText(), DocFlavor.STRING, new HashDocAttributeSet());
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
if (pj.printDialog()) {
    PrintService ps = pj.getPrintService();
    DocPrintJob dpj = ps.createPrintJob();
    dpj.print(document, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
}
```

If you don't want a dialog, you can always get the default printer with `PrintServiceLookup.getDefaultPrintService()`.